# Coleção imutável adicionando strings

Tags: java, array, lista, nullpointerexception

Estou iniciando programação em java e estou tendo um problema ao criar uma coleção imutável. Abaixo está o que criei:

```
package br.com.estudos;

import java.util.Collection;


public class MinhaColecaoImutavel<String> extends MinhaColecao<String> {


    public static MinhaColecaoImutavel instancia;


    public static synchronized MinhaColecaoImutavel getinstancia(Collection<?> colecao) {
        if (instancia == null) {
            instancia = new MinhaColecaoImutavel(colecao);
        }

        return instancia;
    }

    private MinhaColecaoImutavel(Collection<String> colecao) {
        instancia.addAll(colecao);
    }

}
```

Ao executar a main pelo comando abaixo,

```
MinhaColecaoImutavel<String> x = MinhaColecaoImutavel.getinstancia(new ArrayList<>());
        x.add("x");
```

Me dá o erro `NullPointerException` na linha "`instancia.addAll(colecao)`". O meu x é para adicionar um valor na instância para que não fique nula.

Alguém tem uma luz para ajudar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Esse campo estático significa que é impossível utilizar-se duas instâncias de `MinhaColecaoImutavel`. Isso é uma péssima ideia, afinal de contas, não deveria haver problema algum em criar-se duas instâncias distintas dessa classe em locais diferentes para finalidades diferentes. Por, exemplo, em um local eu crio uma coleção imutável com nomes de impressoras e um uma outra parte do código totalmente diferente eu crio uma lista imutável com palavras lidas de um dicionário. Com esse código, a mesma lista vai ser retornada em ambos os casos, ocasionando confusão, dor e sofrimento. O `static` não deve ser usado dessa forma.

A solução é simples. Esqueça o `static` e o método estático e use o construtor diretamente:

```
package br.com.estudos;

import java.util.Collection;

public class MinhaColecaoImutavel<String> extends MinhaColecao<String> {
    public MinhaColecaoImutavel(Collection<String> colecao) {
        this.addAll(colecao);
    }
}
```

E você usa assim:

```
MinhaColecaoImutavel<String> x = new MinhaColecaoImutavel(new ArrayList<>());
x.add("x");
```

No entanto, isso ainda não está certo. Observe que a classe `MinhaColecaoImutavel` não adiciona nada à superclasse além de um construtor. Uma vez que uma instância da subclasse foi construída, ela não tem nada de diferente do que é oferecido pela superclasse. Isso significa que isso é um mau uso de herança que não traz benefício algum. A solução é colocar o construtor na superclasse (estou supondo que o tipo genérico é `T`):

```
    public MinhaColecao(Collection<T> colecao) {
        this.addAll(colecao);
    }
```

E você usa assim:

```
MinhaColecao<String> x = new MinhaColecao(new ArrayList<>());
x.add("x");
```

Se a sua ideia é fazer uma subclasse imutável de uma superclasse mutável, essa não é uma boa ideia. O melhor seria ter uma interface definindo a sua coleção e ter duas implementações distintas, uma mutável e uma imutável. O uso de métodos concretos com o modificador `default` na interface (permitido a partir do Java 8) deve te ajudar a simplificar o código das implementações.